# flyway не создает таблицу и выбрасывает исключение

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, flyway

У меня стандартное Rest Spring Bott Application, в котором пока что только одна таблица. Я сразу подключил flyway, чтобы создавать ее автоматически заполнять данными. Для начала подключил зависимость в pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

После этого в resources создал структуру папок db.migration и добавил свой скрипт, который назвал V1__Data.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE sensors(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    model VARCHAR(15),
    range_from INT,
    range_to INT,
    type VARCHAR(11),
    unit VARCHAR(7),
    location VARCHAR(40),
    description VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO sensors(name, model, range_from, range_to, type, unit, location, description) VALUES
    ('Sensor 1', 'PC33-56', 0, 16, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number one'),
    ('Sensor 2', 'EH-567', -25, 25, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number two'),
    ('Sensor 3', 'TER-21', -70, 50, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number three'),
    ('Sensor 4', 'H94', 0, 100, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room3', 'This sensor has number four'),
    ('Sensor 5', 'GD-23', 0, 30, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number five'),
    ('Sensor 6', 'LC-11', 5, 10, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room3', 'This sensor has number six'),
    ('Sensor 7', 'RFD-84', 15, 75, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number seven'),
    ('Sensor 8', 'QQ-12', 40, 80, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number eight'),
    ('Sensor 9', 'LL_3', -3, 10, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number nine'),
    ('Sensor 10', 'PC33-56', -5, 50, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number ten'),
    ('Sensor 11', 'H94', 5, 10, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number eleven'),
    ('Sensor 12', 'EH-567', 0, 50, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number twelve'),
    ('Sensor 13', 'PC33-56', 3, 10, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number thirteen'),
    ('Sensor 14', 'GD-23', 0, 100, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number fourteen'),
    ('Sensor 15', 'TER-21', 0, 30, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number fifteen'),
    ('Sensor 16', 'LL_3', 3, 10, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number sixteen'),
    ('Sensor 17', 'EH-567', 0, 30, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room3', 'This sensor has number seventeen'),
    ('Sensor 18', 'H94', -25, 25, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number eighteen'),
    ('Sensor 19', 'GD-23', -70, 50, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number nineteen'),
    ('Sensor 20', 'EH-567', 0, 100, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number twenty'),
    ('Sensor 21', 'LL_3', 3, 10, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number twenty one'),
    ('Sensor 22', 'TER-21', -25, 25, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room2', 'This sensor has number twenty two'),
    ('Sensor 23', 'PC33-56', -70, 50, 'Temperature', '°С', 'Room3', 'This sensor has number twenty three'),
    ('Sensor 24', 'H94', -25, 25, 'Voltage', 'voltage', 'Room1', 'This sensor has number twenty four'),
    ('Sensor 25', 'QQ-12',0, 30, 'Pressure', 'bar', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number twenty five'),
    ('Sensor 26', 'EH-567', 0, 100, 'Humidity', '%', 'Room4', 'This sensor has number twenty six');
```

После этого добавил entity:

```
package com.example.labinventtaskbackend.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sensors")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class SensorEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "range_from")
    private Integer rangeFrom;
    @Column(name = "range_to")
    private Integer rangeTo;
    private String type;
    private String unit;
    private String location;
    private String description;
}
```

И в properties добавил запись

```
**здесь становил url, user, password для подключения к db
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

После этого запускаю приложение и получаю ошибки:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [sensors]
```

При этом таблица миграций в базе данных создается

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось flyway не видел sql-скрипт миграции, я по новой создал структуру папок и все заработало